# How to obtain distinct values based on another column in the same table?

Tags: mariadb, heidisql

I'm not sure how to word the title properly so sorry if it wasn't clear at first.

What I want to do is to find users that have logged into a specific page, but not the other.

The table I have looks like this:

```
Users_Logins
------------------------------------------------------
| IDLogin | Username | Page  | Date       | Hour     |
|---------|----------|-------|------------|----------|
| 1       | User_1   | Url_1 | 2019-05-11 | 11:02:51 |
| 2       | User_1   | Url_2 | 2019-05-11 | 14:16:21 |
| 3       | User_2   | Url_1 | 2019-05-12 | 08:59:48 |
| 4       | User_2   | Url_1 | 2019-05-12 | 16:36:27 |
| ...     | ...      | ...   | ...        | ...      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

So as you can see, User 1 logged into Url 1 and 2, but User 2 logged into Url 1 only.

How should I go about finding users that logged into Url 1, but never logged into Url 2 during a certain period of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to improve the title of your question later, but for the time being, this is how I accomplished what you are asking for:

**Query:**

```
select distinct username from User_Logins  
where page = 'Url_1'  
and username not in  
    (select username from User_Logins  
    where Page = 'Url_2')  
and date BETWEEN '2019-05-12' AND '2019-05-12'  
and hour BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '12:00:00';
```

**Returns:**

```
User_2
```

**Comments:**

1. I basically used a sub query to filter out the usernames you don't care about. :)
2. The time range is getting only 1 result, which you can test by removing the  "distinct" in the first line of the query. If you then remove the time range from the query, you'll get 2 results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `group by username` and apply the conditions in a `HAVING` clause:

```
select username 
from User_Logins  
where
  date between '..........' and '..........'  
  and 
  hour between '..........' and '..........';
group by username
having 
  sum(page = 'Url_1') > 0
  and 
  sum(page = 'Url_2') = 0
```

Replace the dots with the date/time intervals you want.

Comment: By the way, I answered to the other commenter that their solution worked, but this actually also worked. Thanks a lot!